# Cannot build PLY lexer using ideone

Tags: python, lex, ply

I'm trying to create a MCVE for a question I'm going to ask later, but I've come across a problem with the online IDE I'm trying to use, ideone.

The code in the link below works perfectly fine if I run it in my local Python 2.7 interpreter:

http://ideone.com/DpALEU

However, on ideone, the errors I get are:

```
ERROR: prog.py:282: No regular expression defined for rule 't_DIRECTIVE'
ERROR: prog.py:286: No regular expression defined for rule 't_REFERENCE'
ERROR: prog.py:291: No regular expression defined for rule 't_UNAME'
ERROR: prog.py:296: No regular expression defined for rule 't_USTRING'
ERROR: prog.py:301: No regular expression defined for rule 't_UFLOAT'
ERROR: prog.py:307: No regular expression defined for rule 't_HEX'
ERROR: prog.py:314: No regular expression defined for rule 't_INTEGER'
ERROR: prog.py:320: No regular expression defined for rule 't_COMMENT'
ERROR: prog.py:324: No regular expression defined for rule 't_ID'
ERROR: prog.py:330: No regular expression defined for rule 't_newline'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 338, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ply/lex.py", line 901, in lex
    raise SyntaxError("Can't build lexer")
SyntaxError: Can't build lexer
```

However, I'm defining my rules validly. For example:

```
def t_REFERENCE(t):
    r'([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\s*\'([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\''
    return t
```

What would be causing this error?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suspect the nested single quotes.

Comment: I don't think that's the case since `r'\#(\w+)\s+(.+)'` (`t_DIRECTIVE`) doesn't contain any `'` characters within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably ideone uses the `-OO` optimization setting, which removes all docstrings. Consequently, the `lex` module cannot find the docstrings when it wants to build the scanner. A similar problem would be encountered in the parser.

Here is an ugly workaround: http://ideone.com/H5rxXK

There is a clean workaround recommended by the [PLY manual](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn37) (see the next section -- *8. Using Python's Optimized Mode* -- after the link; the "correct" link doesn't currently work because of an HTML error in the PLY manual). Unfortunately, it produces [a different error](http://ideone.com/nA4R15), presumably the result of ideone's filesystem virtualization.